# How to make a dive slightly tilt in transform skew

Tags: html, css

I want a structure like this

[image]

But i'm unable to get this structure with this codes :

HTML CODE

```
<div class="row footer-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="copyright">
            <p class="text-center copy-text">Copyright &copy; 2017 Brown Box Ninja. All rights Reserved</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS CODE

```
.footer-bottom {

background-color: #000;
min-height: 140px;
-ms-transform: skew(0deg,8deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: skew(20deg,10deg); /* Safari */
transform: skew(0deg,8deg); /* Standard syntax */
}

.copyright {

color: #fff;
font-family: calibri;
font-size: 16px;
}

.copy-text {
padding-top: 5%;
}
```

I want a straight bottom line and a slightly tilt top line as shown in the picture. Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.footer-bottom:before{background-color: #000; position:absolute; top:-50px; left:0px; content:""; width:100%;
min-height: 80px;
-ms-transform: skew(0deg,2deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: skew(0deg,2deg); /* Safari */
transform: skew(0deg,2deg); /* Standard syntax */}
 .footer-bottom { position:relative; padding-top:50px; margin-top:80px;

background-color: #000;
min-height: 140px;

}

.copyright {

color: #fff;
font-family: calibri;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row footer-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="copyright">
            <p class="text-center copy-text">Copyright &copy; 2017 Brown Box Ninja. All rights Reserved</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that using `pseudo selector` as below,

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #111;
  transform: skewY(5deg) translate(0px, 40px);
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #111;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: skewY(-5deg) translate(0px, 40px);
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Check this codes as per your provided codes, you need to use `pseudo selector` as said along-with translate to fill gap between two divs.

```css
.footer-bottom {
  background-color: #000;
  min-height: 120px;
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 8deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg, 10deg);
  /* Safari */
  transform: skew(0deg, 8deg);
  /* Standard syntax */
  transform-origin: top left;
  position: relative;
}

.footer-bottom:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  background: #000;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: skew(0deg, -8deg) translate(0, -40px);
}

.copyright {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.copy-text {
  padding-top: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: skew(0deg, -8deg);
  line-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row footer-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="copyright">
      <p class="text-center copy-text">Copyright &copy; 2017 Brown Box Ninja. All rights Reserved</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```